# Error 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am developing a project locally and at the time of upload to hosting (both Apache server), there are two files that give me problems, one of them the server returns me the error '403 forbidden 'and the other does not I absolutely return anything.

These two files are in a directory that contains the drivers for the actions of users of the website, along with 17 others are PHP scripts that work properly.

I thought it was due to lack of permissions, so I changed to 777 in the directory so that affected all sub-directories and files stored in it, but still failing.

Then I thought it would be a rule file. Htaccess but neither. I deleted all the rules and still failing just those two.

Anyone would think that may be happening?

A greeting.

PS: I've been doing some of the solutions that have already been answered in another post, but no solution.

## SOLVED

I looked at the error logs and everything came caused by 'Modsegurity' module so I disabled it and I do not need and everything returned to run correctly.

Thank you all for the answers.

Comment: Please include *what* you've tried other than just saying "I tried some solutions".

Comment: Rules similar to those you find in .htaccess access may also be present in apache configuration file. Check there. For Centos it is at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

Comment: Also, .htaccess files that are in parent directories may have rewrite rules and other kinds of rules that affect their subdirectories. You will want to check parent directories of this particular directory for .htaccess files as well.

Comment: Your apache server not allowed the directory to access via the network. default is deny from all

Answer (score 0):

Your apache server not allowed the directory to access via the network. default is deny from all.

You should edit your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file and change `deny from all` to `allow from all` under your web directory section